# compare rows of two query set result in same table

Tags: php, mysql

I have table where I store data on basis of date.

Now I need to check that: is there any difference between data of rows with two different dates.

In a simple way you can say that I have two queries which select data from same table now I have to compare each row and column value. for example my two query are -

```
SELECT *  FROM `national` WHERE `upload_date` = '2015-08-04'  // return 106 rows
```

and

```
SELECT *  FROM `national` WHERE `upload_date` = '2015-08-01'   // return 106 rows
```

I have tried to compare this with below query but the result not seem to be correct to me, I am not satisfy with this.

```
Select U.* from 
(SELECT t1.* FROM `national` t1 where upload_date = '2015-08-01'
union all
SELECT t2.*  FROM `national` t2 WHERE `upload_date` = '2015-08-04' ) U
GROUP BY emp_id, uqi_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Can Any one please provide me correct query ?? thank you

Comment: I'm not sure of the MySQL way, but `array_diff()` would be your PHP way out

Comment: yeah and that may be work too but I think that would be a long process. It can be done with a single MySQL query, I am looking for that.

Comment: If you only need to compare a single date, not really. If you're comparing thousands upon thousands then yeah, it's going to add a lot more processing time. I'm sure it can be done with MySQL too so hope you get the answer you're looking for :)

Comment: thanks @zanderwar for the links but I have already check them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 (
  SELECT t1.* 
  FROM 
     `national` t1, `national` t2 
  where
      t1.upload_date = '2015-08-01' and t2.upload_date='2015-08-04' and
      -- put your columns here that you want to compare for same DATA
      -- like t1.name=t2.name and etc...
 )
```

Comment: According to you what would be the result of this query, does is it return the mismatch column or match ?

Comment: If you write `=` by replacing my commented code it will return matched rows or if you write `!=` it will return the mismatch rows..

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like that

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `national` WHERE upload_date = '2015-08-01') a
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM `national` WHERE upload_date = '2015-08-04') b
     ON a.emp_id = b.emp_id AND a.uqi_id = b.uqi_id
ORDER BY uqi_id
```

Comment: This query return empty result set. what is that mean according to you, does is return empty mismatch result or what??